# check all the processes which are taking more than 5% of cpu

Tags: unix, command-line, shell

How do I check all the processes which are taking more than 5% of CPU on HPUX

Answer (score 1):

The usual thing to do is to run `top` or `top -o cpu`.

```
top(1)                                                                  top(1)

NAME
       top - display and update sorted information about processes

SYNOPSIS
       top    [-a | -d | -e | -c <mode>]
              [-F | -f]
              [-h]
              [-i <interval>]
              [-l <samples>]
              [-ncols <columns>]
              [-o <key>] [-O <skey>]
              [-R | -r]
              [-S]
              [-s <delay>]
              [-n <nprocs>]
              [-stats <keys>]
              [-pid <processid>]
              [-user <username>]
              [-U <username>]
              [-u]

DESCRIPTION
       The  top program periodically displays a sorted list of system process-
       es.  The default sorting key is pid, but other keys  can  be  used  in-
       stead.  Various output options are available.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UNIX95=1 ps -eopid,cpu|awk '$2>5{print $1}'
```